# Disable mouse hover event on Windows globally without blocking mousemove

Tags: node.js, windows, autohotkey

I've made a Node/AutoHotKey script to control two computers with one mouse. I've made the cursor disappear on the first computer when using the second computer (https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6167), but the mouseover event is still firing of course.

What I mean is simply if you hover over some icons on the desktop you will see tooltips, and so on.

I'm using a graphics tablet (absolute positioning), the cursor position gets captured and sent to the second computer.

I've found this method:
Found it here: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=33128 (Also from the documentation: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/BlockInput.htm)

`BlockInput, MouseMove ;to disable mouse interaction`

`BlockInPut, MouseMoveOff ;to enable mouse interaction`

But it blocks `mousemove` completely, so that the cursor stops moving at all.

Is there any way to programmatically disable/enable `mouseover` (so that buttons don't change their color and tooltips don't appear, but AutoHotKey could still capture cursor position) event globally on Windows without blocking `mousemove`?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but https://symless.com/synergy does keyboard/mouse sharing, which might solve your underlying problem and doesn't need you to write any code.

Comment: Yes, synergy works well with a mouse, but I'm using a graphics tablet: https://members.symless.com/forums/topic/315-will-synergy-work-with-wacom-tablets/